# Global Positioning System in j2me

Tags: java-me, gps, jsr179

Can I use GPS in J2me enabled phones?

I am curious to know whether one can use GPS in J2ME enabled phone or can create an application based on GPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSR 179 Location API for J2ME** is intended to support creation of applications based on GPS, see [JSR 179 specification page, section 2.5](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=179):

> ...this API shall work with most positioning methods, such as GPS...

If you are interested in more details, below tutorials make for a good start:

- [Develop a location-based service application using JSR 179](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/wi-mobilesa/)
- [Developing Location Based Services: Introducing the Location API for J2ME](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-location-based-services-introducing-location-api-j2me)